# Guidelines for using extensions in Swift

Tags: single-responsibility, encapsulation, swift-language

The other day, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67937384/how-to-solve-redundant-conformance-to-protocol-error-when-including-swift-packag) question on StackOverflow. In short, the user who asked the question wanted to extend a class from a third-party library to implement the `Codable` protocol, but another library had already defined an extension to do just that, and the user preferred his own implementation.

I come from a strong object-oriented background, so the fact that Swift allows extensions anywhere with no restrictions seems to me like a violation of encapsulation. This particular example also makes me think of libraries in C++ that throw `using namespace std` into public-facing header files. What guidelines could the Swift community adopt to prevent issues like this?

Comment: An arbitrary Swift extension (i.e one not defined in the same module or file as the object itself) can only access the public members of the object. Can you explain how this violates encapsulation?

Answer (score 5):

The community convention is that libraries should never define conformance of a type that isn't theirs (in this case, `CoreLocation.CCLLocationCoordinate2D`) to a protocol that isn't theirs (in this case, `Swift.Codable`).

Libraries should limit themselves to:

1. Conforming their own types to their own protocols
2. Conforming their own types to others' protocols
3. Conforming others' types to their own protocols

There were talks about improving this story (either with some way to explicitly resolve conflicts, or to restrict them from being defined in the first place). Have a search on the Swift forums, there's several big posts about it.

In my opinion, MapBox is misbehaving. They should never have extended `CCLLocationCoordinate2D` with `Codable`. They should have wrapped `CCLLocationCoordinate2D` in a struct that's unique to their library, and conformed *that* to `Codable`. However, their probably can't change it now, without a breaking API change.

As a result, consumers are forced to remove their `CCLLocationCoordinate2D: Codable` conformance, and make wrapper types instead.